# Groovy: dynamically add properties to groovy classes from inside class methods

Tags: groovy, properties

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    def myMethod() {
        variable = "I am a variable"
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        println "Missing property $name"
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.myProperty
myClass.myMethod();
```

At myClass.myProperty, `Missing property myProperty` was printed out to the console.

But then in `myClass.myMethod()`, groovy makes no attempt to go to `propertyMissing` but instead just throws a

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: variable for class: MyClass
```

Some search online indicates that it is because `myClass.myProperty` calls a getter method, which redirects to propertyMissing.

I am guessing that within class methods, groovy doesn't go through getter methods for variables and that's why propertyMissing is not getting called?

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do using the dynamic `propertyMissing`, or `getProperty`, or anything like that?

P.S. I don't want to do `def variable = ...` or `String variable = ...` in myMethod. I am hoping that the syntax within `myMethod` will stay as `variable = ...`, but adding anything outside of that method is acceptable.

Comment: Why does groovy, throws an error on executing `myClass.myMethod();` when the keyword `def` or any data type keyword like `string` is been missing?

Comment: I believe you can only set variable without def-ing or declaring when you are running it in a script. When you run it in a script without def-ing or declaring, then the variable is put into the script's Binding (which you can access with the getBinding() call when in the script). However, when you are not running a script, there isn't a "Binding", and Groovy expects you to use def or to declare it using the data type.

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make your class `extend Expando` ([Expando is described here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html))

```
class MyClass extends Expando {
    def myMethod() {
        variable = "I am a variable"
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        println "Missing property $name"
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.myProperty
myClass.myMethod()
println myClass.variable
```

You can hand-roll a similar functionality by creating your own backing map for variables, and writing the `get/setProperty` methods yourself, ie:

```
class MyClass {

    def myMethod() {
        variable = "I am a variable"
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        println "Missing property $name"
    }

    def backingMap = [:]

    Object getProperty( String property ) {
      if( backingMap[ property ] == null ) {
        propertyMissing( property )
      }
      else {
        backingMap[ property ]
      }
    }

    void setProperty( String property, Object value ) {
      backingMap[ property ] = value
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.myProperty
myClass.myMethod()
println myClass.variable
```

Though as you can see from the [source code for Expando](https://github.com/matthewmccullough/groovy-core/blob/trunk/src/main/groovy/util/Expando.java#L71), this hand-rolled version does a lot less checks and I'd trust it less ;-)

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! I actually was working with getProperty before... but had forgot that I'm trying to set (not get) a property and didn't implement setProperty... but your way with the Expando is even better. =] Accepted as answer