# Not able to dynamically add method to Groovy using metaClass from within instance

Tags: groovy

I'm afraid I'm a beginner in Groovy so this might be very silly. (using groovy 2.3.4)
I have the following code:

```
class Test {

    public void method() {
        def methodName = "dynamicMethodName"
        this.metaClass."$methodName" = {->}
        this."${methodName}"()
    }
}

new Test().method()
```

Running this will throw the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dynamicMethodName for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dynamicMethodName for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
at Test.method(what.groovy:5)
at Test$method.call(Unknown Source)
at what.run(what.groovy:10)
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I also tried not being 'too dynamic' and altered the code like so:

```
class Test {

    public void method() {
        this.metaClass.dynamicMethodName = {->}
        this.dynamicMethodName()
    }
}

new Test().method()
```

But I still get the same error

*UPDATE*

It seems that if I add the method outside the class by using an instance reference instead of using *this*, it works.

Is there no way to dynamically add methods for an instance from within the instance itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, if the class extends the class Expando, it works.

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7079038/56242

Comment: Or use `ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()` for the script before invoking method().